# How to establish connection on signalR hub using only websockets from js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, websocket, signalr

I am running api using .net core web app, created a server with hub so i can send messages to a group of users or all of the users. Basically I use hubconnectionbuilder on the client side and it works, but want to create case for connecting only trough websockets from client side.

I already managed to connect to a server and subscribe to a hub, but can't figure out how to establish bi-directional communication.

Simply I don't get response from server, only sending messages not receiving anything from server.

Comment: Please go through this link. It contains complete details about SignalR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: i did, couldn't find what i need